# How should I program a window manager in Qt?

Tags: linux, qt, user-interface, qml

I'm thinking about making a basic window manager for Linux based off of X11 and using the Qt toolkit. QML looks like a good language, so I'll probably use that. The problem is that I've never coded a WM before. I know that the ICCCM and EWMH will be required reading but beyond that my knowledge is foggy. Are there any other resources I should look into before jumping in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The window manager itself will probably not be written in Qt, as Qt is just an interface for drawing graphics into the windows themselves
- Start by reading up on some XLib/XCB documentation and getting some basic things showing up like  windows with pix-maps(images) in them
- Write some test QML/Qt applications to gain knowledge in that
- Test, find bugs, cry, debug, rinse and repeat

P.S need any help? This sounds like a fun project :D

Comment: Thanks for the information! If/when things start rolling along I'll be sure to let you in! ;)